# How can I translate Facebook user data into records on my database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, oauth, devise, facebook-login

I'm using the `omniauth-facebook` gem with `devise` to set up Facebook login on my website. I'm at the point of importing Facebook user data into my database, but I'm having some weird issues.

Here's my method used to import the data:

```
#User.rb

def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
    user.email = auth.info.email.to_s
    user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
    user.username = auth.info.name
  end
end
```

The record I get back has a `user.username` equal to the Facebook email, and the `user.email` is nil. `auth.info.name` (which is actually the email address) is the only piece of Facebook user data I'm actually able to recover. Everything else comes back nil.

Has anyone else encountered this?

Comment: You didn't tag which language you are using ...

Comment: @ASTEFANI Good catch, it's rails.

Comment: @JoeMorano is my post below answers your question?

Comment: Why don't you put `Rails.logger.debug "AUTH: #{auth}"` before your `where` statement and see in the server log what you are actually getting from Facebook. Also, `auth.info.email` can be `nil` because some users may not allow you to see their email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using `user` instead of `member` inside of the `first_or_create` block? Is it a typo while creating a code snippet?

Anyway, I believe that the issue is for users that exists in database. In such case block that is passed to the `first_or_create` method isn't evaluated (yield is only for new records) so fields are not updated.

Make sure that you specified those fields (or didn't specified only name) in omniauth-facebook configuration: https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook. It returns name and email by default.

You should also take a look at the great [RailsCasts about Facebook Authentication](http://railscasts.com/episodes/360-facebook-authentication).